# How to search for parent id in view from model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor, parent-child

I need to display some parent-child relation data in view.
Following is my code:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Test.Domain.TestTable> 
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Parent</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentID)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td>
            Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
            -----------------
            -----------------
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to display the parent name instead of parent id, which has following structure in database:
 **ID** **Name** **ParentID**
 **1**  **John**   **Null**
 **2**  **Dean**  **1**
 **3**  **Sam**   **1**

---

To display parent name, I tried following code, but none of this works:

- `@Model.Where(screenParent => screenParent.ID == item.ParentID).Select(screenParent => new { screenParent.Name})`
  It displays
  `` System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Test.Domain.TestTable,<>f__AnonymousType5`1[System.String]] ``

---

Can you suggest why it display above line of code? 
Also what can be done to achieve the parent name instead of parent id.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you include ParentName in your Test.Domain.TestTable model using linq anonymous types? i.e. add the ParentName in your model from the controller side and on the view directly do this: modelItem=>item.ParentName

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or some other ORM?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a couple of assumptions here.

Do you have a property on your model for Parent instead or are you just pulling in ParentID?  If you are pulling in just the ID i suggest changing your model/mapping so that you are pulling in the entire object reference by the FK.

If you are already pulling in the entire Parent object, know that entity framework won't automatically lazy load your Parent for you.  You have to explicitly tell it to load it when you query TestTable.

You can do this in 2 different ways.

1. Make your Parent property Virtual.  i.e.

   public virtual TestTable Parent { get; set; }

   Then when you try and access TestTable.Parent it will load from the database.  This will allow you to access the name.
2. Explicitly load Parent when you query test table i.e.

   myDBContext.TestTables.Include("YourParentPropertyName").Where(....);

The end results in your view will look like this:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Parent.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ben.
I've used second option to display parent name.

Comment: I made foreign key relationship between ID & parent id,that introduced & a navigational property & then fetching the parent name was easy.

But still, if anybody can suggest me why view was rendering "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Test.Domain.TestTable,<>f__AnonymousType5`1[System.String]]" when I tried to find parent name in view by searching in Model. It should have thrown some error if no matches found.

Comment: Just a guess.  try @Model.FirstOrDefault(screenParent => screenParent.ID == item.ParentID).Select(screenParent => new { screenParent.Name}).  What you originally had returns an enumerable query which you would have to convert to a list using the method ToList(), and then take the first entry.  Using FirstOrDefault will only return 1 object of whatever type you are selecting or null.